# ¿Partición fantasma? windows

Tags: windows

Así se encuentra actualmente mi disco particionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando entro en "Mi pc" en la seccion de información del equipo solo me sale una partición que se llama C: que es la principal de 418 GB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaria saber si puedo unir esa partición "fantasma" a mi partición principal C: sin perder ninguna informacion de C: o dañarla

Comment: esa particion no la vez por que no tiene nombre

Comment: ok, pero como puedo hacer para unirla a C:? @JackNavaRow

Comment: no conozco una forma que no sea formatear, lo que puedes es crear otra unidad y agregarcela

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes ningún dato dentro, haz clic derecho y dale a eliminar volumen, eso lo dejará sin formato.

A continuación, haz click derecho en la espacio de mayor tamaño (Unidad C:) y dale a extender volumen. Te aparecerá una ventana donde te dice qué parte quieres añadirle y te debe aparecer la que tienes sin formato.

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio respondiendo a preguntas que sean realizadas en base al [help].

Comment: No entiendo por qué, si se supone que este tipo de preguntas no se deben hacer en este foro, corregís las entradas en lugar de borrarlas directamente. ¿No sería eso mejor que ir poniendo comentarios a los que tratan de responder?

Comment: ¿Propones que corrija lo que escribes o la pregunta que se realizó? , es importante leer [ask] y [answer] para que no exista duda que y como preguntar/responder.

Comment: Propongo que si no queréis que se respondan este tipo de preguntas, ni si quiera perdáis el tiempo en editarlas y las borréis directamente. O si lo que queréis es que se vean bien ortográficamente, aprovechad y bloqueadlas para que no se puedan responder.

Answer (score 0):

En principio no puedes extenderla desde la interfaz del mismo Windows qué tienes instalado en C. Deberías usar Gparted, SystemRescue o cualquier otro para poder extenderlo.

Lo que sí puedes hacer desde el mismo Windows es asignarle una letra y alojar en ella los datos importantes para así después poder hacerle copias de seguridad automatizadas y con un buen plan de ejecución.

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio respondiendo a preguntas que sean realizadas en base al [help].

Answer (score 0):

Para unir esa partición sin formatear debes bootear por una unidad externa, por ejemplo puedes usar gparted solo descarga la imagen iso grábala en un disco y edita la partición, primero debes eliminar la partición que esta ocupando espacio y segundo re-dimensionar la partición principal para ocupar el espacio liberado.

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio respondiendo a preguntas que sean realizadas en base al [help].